# How to unite `brew` and `brew cask` into one command?

Tags: homebrew

I don't know why I should care how exactly an application is distributed.

How can I make Homebrew use only one command to install formulas and casks, like traditional *nix package managers do `apt-get install app`?

Comment: You probably could script something by parsing the output of `brew search`. How would you handle conflicts if a package is available several times?

Comment: Conflicts resolution is supposed to be the package manager's job. Also, why would the same app be available both as a formula and a cask?

Comment: If you want to propose a change on how Homebrew works, wouldn’t contacting the Homebrew crew be the better option?

Comment: Also, try to run `brew search emacs` for an example of a conflict. But if this isn't an issue for you, `brew install FOO || brew cask install FOO` should work (and can easily be put into a shell function or script).

Comment: Looks like your edit took the joking 4 min part out. I’ve removed my comment and your response. Hope that’s Ok.

Comment: IMHO casks aren't at the same quality yet. Upgrading them is still a pain. Also casks may ask for administrator passwords and may install anywhere on the system. Personally I use the only as last resort.  Though I agree as `brew search` already considers casks `install` should as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this function to .zshrc. It tries to install a cask, then a formula:

```
bru () {
    ! ( brew cask install "$argv[@]" ) && brew install "$argv[@]"
}
```